# Zero- and one-inflated beta regression modeling using zoib package in R

Tags: r, regression

I am working with species distribution. As response variables, I have the are for three different patterns (filling, expansion, unfilling), that can be transformed into a proportion [0-1], if compared to the total area available. Two of the response variables are zero-inflated, while one of them is one-inflated. As predictors, I have body mass and dispersal.
As my data are bounded between 0 and 1 but I also have several 0s and 1s, I thought I needed a zero-one inflated beta regression model, which I looked up in R using `zoib` package. It would be great if I could model the three response variables and the two covariates all together, but first I tried with only one (response and covariate), but I am already failing. As it's not a very common model technique, I am struggling to find online help.
This is a sample of my data:

```
myData <- structure(list(filling = c(0.3833, 0, 0.0103, 0, 0.0228, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0.1975, 0.0559, 0.0796, 0.0755, 0, 0, 0, 0.0572, 0.4701, 
0.2258), expansion = c(0.5052, 0.2222, 0.9381, 0.75, 0.035, 0.9375, 
1, 0.9855, 0.0038, 0.25, 0.4459, 0.9441, 0.0845, 0.2956, 0.1, 
0.8444, 1, 0.0804, 0.2594, 0.3226), unfilling = c(0.0458, 0, 
0, 0, 0.6717, 0, 0, 0, 0.2123, 0, 0.1624, 0, 0.6285, 0.0063, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0757, 0.1682, 0), adult_mass_g = c(92500, 45500, 277.615, 
278, 77000, 21666.685, 21666.7, 19928.335, 131250, 160166.665, 
52999.99, 10.6, 63612.305, 777.95, 771, 85, 140.045, 483.5, 12760.04, 
19166.665), dispersal = c(12.785, 8.654, 0.524, 0.524, 11.558, 
5.754, 5.754, 5.496, 17.291, 17.291, 9.411, 0.7, 10.405, 5.748, 
5.722, 0.273, 0.36, 5.737, 4.301, 5.379)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is what I tried so far:

```
zoib(filling ~ adult_mass_g | 0 | adult_mass_g, 
     data = myData,
     zero.inflation = T,
     one.inflation = F)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in rnorm((p.xsum - 1) * 4, 0, 0.1) : invalid arguments
```

But I cannot understand what type of error this is.